# Are there any datasets for electric vehicle range estimation?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, transportation

Are there any datasets out there which provide details about an electric vehicle, the trips it took and change in remaining range? Or something similar which can be used to test on machine learning algorithms.

Edit:
I found the the chargecar dataset [here](http://www.chargecar.org/data/do_search?filter=&filter_type=none&page=1) after looking through some papers on range estimation. Anything similar but larger and with more recent cars would be ideal.